# Java AWT canvas in the output is overiding it's own graphic contents

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, awt, java-canvas

I was practising and came across a problem with no perfect explanation of solution.
'''
package com.company;

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    
    public class Main extends Frame {
    
        public Main() {
    
            Button bt = new Button("Click me");
            bt.setBounds(20,40,80,30);
            bt.setBackground(Color.green);
            bt.setForeground(Color.blue);
    
            Label l1 = new Label("This is label");
            l1.setBounds(20,90,80,30);
    
            TextField tf1 = new TextField();
            tf1.setBounds(20,120,150,30);
    
            TextArea ta = new TextArea();
            ta.setBounds(20,170,350,100);
    
            Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox("cb1");
            cb1.setBounds(200,40,40,40);
            Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox("cb2");
            cb2.setBounds(200,65,40,40);
    
            MyCanvas cv = new MyCanvas();
    
    
            add(bt);
            add(l1);
            add(tf1);
            add(ta);
            add(cb1);
            add(cb2);
            add(cv);
    
            setSize(400,300);
            setLayout(null);
            setVisible(true);
            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    Frame frame = (Frame)e.getSource();
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            });
    
            bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    l1.setText("button click...");
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
            Main m = new Main();
        }
    }
    
    class MyCanvas extends Canvas{
        public MyCanvas(){
            setBackground(Color.cyan);
            setBounds(250,40,100,100);
        }
    
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawOval(240,42,70,50);
            g.drawString("JAVA is best",252,94);
        }
    }
```

'''
And the output is as shown in the image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsxF4.png]

I did find out that the graphics contents are getting hidden behind the canvas in the frame. PLease explain what is causing such output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setBounds(250,40,100,100);
 
...

g.drawString("JAVA is best",252,94);
```

Graphics are painted relative to the component. The width of your component is only 100, so attempting to paint at 252 is out of bounds of the component.

Try:

```
g.drawString("JAVA is best",52,94);
```

Other suggestions:

1. Don't use AWT. Instead use Swing. Swing components start with "J". See the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. The demo code you find there will be better quality that the code you currently have.
2. Don't use a null layout. Swing (and AWT) were designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: thank you so much bro, for your help and suggestions. I miserably missed out to check out the canvas area.
But, I couldn't figure out this 2nd suggestion of yours, "null layout". were you asking me to use the frame by creating a object of Frame?

Comment: Don't hard code the position of components. That is the way other language might work but Swing/AWT was designed to be used with layout manager to manage the location/size of components on a panel. Read the Swing  tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.